# backup poudriere compile options

Tags: makefile, freebsd, poudriere

When using [poudriere](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?poudriere), how to backup all the custom compiled options so that when creating a new instance/server all the defined ports could recompile as with the selected options.

for example, I create a package like this:

```
poudriere options -cj 11amd64 net/chrony
```

But wondering how to re-use does options to avoid having to configure them again when creating a new setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [poudriere's manual page](https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=poudriere#11)! You can simply copy from `/usr/local/etc/poudriere.d/11amd64-default-options` to another directory. The naming convention of directory is described in manual page.

If you don't have any difference between port options in different jails maybe you may want to use `set`s (with `poudriere bulk -j yourjail -z yourset net/chrony`) - in this case you don't have to copy files.